# In Frontlines, by Marko Kloos, why did Sergeant Fallon get a Medal of Honor?

Tags: frontlines

The series [*Frontlines*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?35727) (2013-2018) states many times that Sergeant Fallon is one of the few living people who have received the Medal of Honor, however I cannot find anywhere  why she got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mentioned at the start of the first book in the series; [Terms of Enlistment](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18800655-terms-of-enlistment).

> “Her name.” Priest gives up his attempt to sneak a peek at Baker’s cards, and leans back in his chair. “Staff Sergeant Fallon. She used to be a First Sergeant, but they busted her down for striking an officer.”
>
> “I thought they kicked you out of the service for hitting a superior,” I say, smelling a military fish tale.
>
> “Oh, they do,” Hansen says. “That’s unless you’re a Medal of Honor winner. They don’t get rid of certified heroes. It would be bad PR.”
>
> **“Medal of Honor?” I ask, and the disbelief in my face makes my three roommates grin with delight. “As in, that blue ribbon with the white stars that goes on top of all the other ribbons?”**
>
> **“That’s the one. She got it when the NAC did that excursion into mainland China a few years back, at the Battle of Dalian. You get the Medal, you can ask for any assignment anywhere in the Service, and she went right back to her old unit once she was out of the hospital.”**

In book three, [Angles of Attack](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24358527-angles-of-attack) we find out a little more about Dalian, but the specifics of her medal-worthy actions are very blurry and it's basically passed off as a [noodle incident](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident).

> I don’t know a lot of Sergeant Fallon’s service history before I met her five years ago in the Territorial Army’s 365th Autonomous Infantry Battalion, but I do know from my former squad mates that the Battle of Dalian was where she earned her Medal of Honor. **I know it was a police action that went south and filled a lot of TA body bags, but the official history is fuzzy on the details, which probably means that we technically or brazenly violated a treaty or three.**
>
> “You have to tell me about that one of these days,” I say.
>
> Sergeant Fallon just smirks. “Andrew, the level of alcohol I need to drink to start telling details about Dalian pretty much guarantees that I won’t be able to recall those details. Speaking of alcohol . . . here we are. Welcome to On the Rocks.”

Comment: I did catch the references mentioned, but havent yet seen the actual reason, as in what she did.

Comment: As I said, it's a noodle incident. I doubt if it'll ever be explored in any detail